# How to make enemy spawn faster

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    if currentTime - self.lastEnemyAdded > 1 { //my lastEnemyAdded is "var lastEnemyAdded : NSTimeInterval = 0.0"
        self.lastEnemyAdded = currentTime + 0.5 //how can i make this -0.1 as the game go longer or if the player reach a certain score
        self.addEnemy() //can someone help me please
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by adding this into ur `didMoveToView` method:

```
runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.runBlock(addEnemy), SKAction.waitForDuration(1.0)])))
```

you can change `waitForDuration` as per your need and into this code after every 1 second `addEnemy()` function will call.

Hope this will help.